# Send fax programmatically with Java

Tags: java, fax

How can i send fax programatically with java?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Woo, Google: [fax4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fax4j/).

**UPDATE:** The fax4j project has moved to [github](https://github.com/sagiegurari/fax4j). Latest releases [hosted here.](https://github.com/sagiegurari/fax4j/releases/latest)

Comment: Is there any charges for sending fax??

Answer (score 4):

Try out [phaxio](http://phaxio.com), it'll probably be the simplest path towards implementation. It's a RESTful api, much cheaper than interfax and it's built specifically for developers.

Answer (score 3):

For even more options, Google: [java fax api](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+fax+api)

For a commercial service with a jar, code samples and a free developer program: http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/java

Answer (score 1):

Hoiio provides a simple RESTful API to send a fax. http://developer.hoiio.com/docs/fax_send.html

You can also receive fax all the same. The charges are by "per minute", since fax are nothing but transmitted data over a phone call.

The Hoiio Java SDK currently does not include fax. But you may fork the SDK and easily add the code for fax.

Disclaimer: I work for Hoiio